# Unique/Sort while keeping rows together in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

"Column A" has unique and sort functions on data imported from another sheet. How do I keep the rest of the columns on the sheet to stick together as the data in "Column A" is constantly changing?

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the spreadsheet you provided.

[image]

I suggest the sheet RECEVING must be formulated differently as follows.

[image]

In the table on the left we can easily add "qty received" 
And the table on right is calulated based on the table of orders in the sheet ORDER and the table on the sheet RECEIVING to get:

1 - Get Drop-down form `ORDER!A2:A` by utilizing [Data validation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop), and entring list from range `ORDER!A2:A`.

2 - Product name as unique values on cell `E2` paste this formula.

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(B2:B),1,1)
```

3 - To get "Total received" on cell `F2` paste

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(E2:E="",,SUMIF(B2:B,E2:E,C2:C)))
```

4 - To get "Ordered" on `G2` paste

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(E2:E="",,SUMIF(ORDER!A:A,E2:E,ORDER!B:B)))
```

5 - lastly "Outstanding" on `H2` paste

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(F2:F="",,F2:F-G2:G))
```

Here is the [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uGeTUU4E7H_g9o0t2N05fw9CGp39rZIBADgUksqHoOw/edit?usp=sharing), I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Here is a sample sheet. On tab "receiving" I would need columns C-I to change accordingly with columns A and B as more entries would be entered from sheet "orders"

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sIVjXlb4ApeSd8iIO1pNpoKzEYpX9b__F_dYNdVpSqM/edit?usp=sharing